# ～ようと.... Japanese grammar

Tags: grammar, meaning

> お百姓と、その息子を殺したヘビ
>
> ヘビがお百姓(ひゃくしょう)の息子の方へはい寄って来て、噛み殺してしまいました。
>   　お父さんのお百姓は、悲しくてたまりません。
>   　それでオノを持ち、ヘビの穴のそばでヘビが出てきたらすぐに**叩き殺そうと**待ち構えていました。
>   　そのうちにヘビが一匹、穴から出てきました。
>   　お百姓は、
>   「それっ！」
>   と、オノを振り下ろしました。
>   　でもヘビは頭を引っ込めてしまい、オノはそばの岩を二つに割っただけでした。
>   　こうなると、お百姓はヘビに仕返しをされたら大変だと思って怖くなりました。
>   　それでヘビに**仲直りをしようと**、言いに行きました。
>   　しかしヘビは首を振って、こう答えました。
>   「あなたもわたしも、今さら気持ち良くお付き合いする事は出来ません。
>   　わたしはこの岩の裂け目を見るたびに。
>   　また、あなたは息子さんのお墓を見るたびに。
>   　嫌な事を思い出すのだから」
>
> このお話しは、深い憎しみを持つ人同士が、仲直り出来る事はめったにないと教えています。
>
> おしまい

From 
http://hukumusume.com/douwa/pc/aesop/08/15.htm

I found that I didn't understand the meaning of the grammar "~ようと　...." when I was reading children stories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ようと` form denotes the intention to do something, or an impending action.

For example, the sentence you've highlighted in the paragraph means to say that,

`"[they] laid in wait by the snake's nest, in an attempt to beat it to death the instant it showed itself."`

Answer (score 3):

> それでオノを持ち、ヘビの穴のそばでヘビが出てきたらすぐに**叩き殺そうと**待ち構えていました。

The "Volitional + と" in your first example means ～(よ)うとして・～(よ)うと思って, "trying to~~" "in an attempt to~~" "with an intent to~~", as the other poster has said. For more info on this grammar, see:

[Volitional + と in ひとまず心を落ち着けようと、[...]](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13441/9831)
[Volitional + と + Verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9688/9831)

---

> それでヘビに仲直りを**しようと**、言いに行きました。

The と in your second example is a quotative particle. You should parse the sentence this way:

> それでヘビに『仲直りをしよう。』と、言いに行きました。
>   So he went to say "Let's make peace." to the snake.

The ようと here cannot be replaced by ようとして or ようと思って.

Comment: 「ようとして・ようと思って」(in an attempt to~~ / trying to~~)って意味なら、「ヘビ**に**仲直りをしようと～～」ではなく「ヘビ**と**仲直りをしようと～～」 になるはずです。