# Is there omission after the とparticle in the text?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "変えようと" in this sentence:

> 根本的なところから変えようとしっかり睡眠をとったり、食生活を見直したりといろいろ取り組んでいますが、その中で皆さんにおすすめしたいのは「音読」です。

Is the と particle implying something like when "思う" is omited in "と思う"?

Comment: Also related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9688/9831

Answer (score 1):

Almost true. 「変えようと」 is considered to be the same as 「変えようと**して**」 or 「変えようと**思って**」 in meaning.
Here, the te-form is used, for proper conjunction with the next part of the sentence.

This pattern often occurs with the form 「～**(よ)うと**」 (positive intention) or 「～**まいと**」 (negative intention).