# Meaning of "Volitional + と + (Non-する verb)"

Tags: particle-と, volitional-form

I'm kind of confused on what does "Volitional + と + Verb" mean in the following sentences:

> i) 心臓を串刺しに**せんと**繰り出される槍の穂先
>
> ii) 手に入れ**ようと**急ぐ

There are two different ways I see to parse it:

1. Same as ようとする but する is ommited. (Don't know if that is grammatical.)
2. と is being used similarly to when it is a "quotation particle" and it's showing the manner in which the verb is done.

Comment: Well I can't understand にせんと in sentence i) but this may help for ii) and more generally: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9688/volitional-%e3%81%a8-verb

Comment: In this case I think it's best to think する is omitted after せんと/まいと/ようと. It's a common pattern.