# What is the meaning of 取り戻そうと in this sentence?

Tags: english-to-japanese, parsing, volitional-form, grammar

In the following sentence:

> 問題を無視することはできません。しかし、
>   問題にばかり注目していると過去の状態を**取り戻そうと**努力することになります

The part where it says: 「取り戻そうと努力することになります」 more specifically that "そうと" where does it come from?
What's the meaning of that 「そうと」?
I really hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9688/volitional-%e3%81%a8-verb

Answer (score 5):

> 「[Verb 1 in Volitional Form] + **と** + [Verb 2]」

should be remembered as a set phrase meaning:

> "[Verb 2] in an attempt to [Verb 1]"

because it is used *very* frequently.

「取{と}り戻{もど}そう」 is, of course, the volitional form of 「取り戻す」.

> "We should not ignore the problem.  If we, however, focused only on the problem, we could end up working (too) hard in an attempt to recover the former situation (instead of making further progress)."