# Function of だと and と in this sentence: 興味のある事だと、あなたは一生懸命に理解しようと努めるでしょう。

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, particles, sentence

興味のある内容で学習しましょう this is the title of original text where I pick up the sentence to give better understanding of what is said.

The sentence is:

> 興味のある事**だと**、あなたは一生懸命に理解しよう**と**努めるでしょう。

I know that と can mean "and", "with", "when A happens B also happens".
What do だと and と mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first だと is actually two words, だ ("is", the copula) and a conditional-と. That is, ～だと means "if [something] is ～...". See [Differences among -たら, なら, -と, -んだったら, -ば, etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/393/5010) and [How Conditionals Work in Japanese: …と, …ば, …たら, and …なら](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/how-conditionals-work/).

The first half of the sentence can be broken down like this:

- 興味がある
  to be interested (more literally, "you have an interest" or "there is an interest")
- 興味のある**事**
  **something** you are interested in
  <sub>(a relative clause with [ga-no conversion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010))</sub>
- 興味のある事**だ**
  (That) **is** something you are interested in.
- 興味のある事だ**と**、...
  **If** that is something you are interested in, ...

---

The second と is part of the ～ようと(する) construction, which means "to try to ～". See [Volitional + と + Verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9688/5010) and [What is the difference between "verb＋て＋みる" and "verb＋(よ)う+とする"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19038/5010). (と by itself is a [marker for the content of an action](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/68132/5010), but you have to memorize -ようと as a set phrase first.) Thus the last half of the sentence means:

- ...あなたは一生懸命に理解**しようと**努めるでしょう。
  ...you will strive hard **trying to understand** it.
  ...you will strive hard **in order to understand** it.